# Does Issei actually sacrifice his arm

Tags: high-school-dxd

In High school DxD, Issei "sacrifices" his arm to get the balance breaker form. But what does sacrifice mean here? He still has his arm and he can still control it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically what happens is that as you said, Issei gives his arm to the dragon in return he get balance breaker. the arm that he traded is now belowing to the dragon, no longer a demon, that is why he was able to hold the cross or the holy water without being hurt in the fight between him and the phoenix.afterwards, the dragon power starts to take over his arms which stops him from having his normal arm and akeno had to suck out the dragon energy for issei could do whatever and not expose that he is a demon.

long story short, he has control over his arm but if akeno wasn't there, his arm would literally be the arm of the dragon
Hope this helps

Comment: Noteworthy that Ddraig and Issei are fused until Issei dies. So for all effects they are two essences in one body. (removing the sacred gear kills the user).

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood, is that his arm is no longer human, it is the one of a dragon, that's why akeno sucks the energy from his hand to give it back it's human form.